# Post html table row data from multiple rows at a time to django model

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, crud

I have a table which is created after a user has selected a number of items from a list. If the user is happy with their selected items, they can submit the items to the backend where i need the items to be saved into the model.

I use javascript to render the selected items in the new table. (Code Below) The data is from a Map where the keys are PKs and the values are objects with the description and price data.

```
  function logMapElements(value, key, map) {
    var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    var itemPK = document.createElement("td");
    itemPK.setAttribute('class', 'id');
    itemPK.textContent = key
    newRow.appendChild(itemPK);
    var itemDescription = document.createElement("td",);
    itemDescription.textContent = value.item
    newRow.appendChild(itemDescription);
    var itemPrice = document.createElement("td");
    itemPrice.textContent = value.price
    newRow.appendChild(itemPrice);
    selectedItemsTableBody.appendChild(newRow);

  }
});
```

**The HTML table;**

```
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-borderless" id="selected_items_table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
            <tbody id="selectedItemsTable">
              <!-- THE SELECTED ITEMS ARE RENDERED HERE -->
            </tbody>
            </form>
          </table>
        </div>
```

**My Django Model**

```
class Selected(models.Model):
    foreignKey = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Im not sure exactly how to write the view to save the data from the rows into the model. Or if i should be writing it in my models to keep my models fat. Is it even possible to be saving the data from multiple rows in a table with one submit button?

**Some example data**

*pk .  Description .  Price*

12 .  Pizza       .  13.50

13 .  Water       .  3.00

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Django already has the features to manage multiple elements in one page (but many forms) and it renders them as a table. The feature you are looking for is
called [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/) so if you decide to use it it should be very easy to include in your current project and ditch the client side rendering.

If you were to continue with the client side rendering then what I would do is generate the formset on the client and reuse the rest of the formset machinery
on the server.

Comment: By generating the formset on the client side do you mean writing the Django code in the javascript table rendering so that it is rendered to the HTML as a from?

Comment: I mean that django expects input tags with some predefined attributes (id, name...) so you would have to recreate them in JS with DOM api